# React Electron ffmpeg-extract-frames build error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, ffmpeg, electron

I am using the npm module ffmpeg-extract-frames for splitting video frames. It works completely fine when I am testing the module in a vanilla node environment. However, when I import the module in my Electron React desktop app component, it gives me a error when building.

This is how I am importing it:

```
const extractFrames = require("ffmpeg-extract-frames");
```

This is the error I am getting when building in my React Electron component:

```
> expedition-hacks-project@0.1.0 build /home/taylorallen/Desktop/expedition-hacks-project
> set "FLUENTFFMPEG_COV=false" && react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index.js
Cannot find module: './lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg'. Make sure this package is installed.

You can install this package by running: npm install ./lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg.


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! expedition-hacks-project@0.1.0 build: `set "FLUENTFFMPEG_COV=false" && react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the expedition-hacks-project@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/taylorallen/.npm/_logs/2020-03-28T22_36_18_100Z-debug.log
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "expedition-hacks-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-fileinput": "^5.0.8",
    "ffmpeg-extract-frames": "^2.0.2",
    "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.2.2",
    "react-icons": "^3.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "homepage": "./",
  "main": "src/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "set \"FLUENTFFMPEG_COV=false\" && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron": "electron ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.2.0",
    "electron-log": "^4.1.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.5"
  }
}
```

I found a github issue https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/573#issuecomment-305408048 addressing this error, and I set FLUENTFFMPEG_COV=0 on in my build script

My scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "set \"FLUENTFFMPEG_COV=false\" && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron": "electron ."
  },
```

Setting the env variable seems to not do anything, I still get the same error.

Comment: quick question regarding the error message did you check if this package is physically exist?
`Cannot find module: './lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg'. Make sure this package is installed.`

Comment: @EvgeniiBazhanov I installed the fluent-ffmpeg module in the project even though it doesn't seem to be a parent module, and it seems to not change anything.